# Ошибка "There was an error parsing the body" в ответе

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, requests

В ответ на POST запрос серверу возвращает 400 статус код, при этом я вроде бы правильно перевел код CURL в python, но он не работает (в cURL работает).

Response:

```
{"detail":"There was an error parsing the body"}
```

Мой код:

```
import requests

url = 'https://background-removal4.p.rapidapi.com/v1/results?mode=fg-image'

headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=---0123456789",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "MY_API_KEY",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "background-removal4.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

with open('test.jpg', 'rb') as img:
    response = requests.post(
        url, headers=headers, files={'image': img})

print(response.text)
```

cURL:

```
curl --request POST \
    --url 'https://background-removal4.p.rapidapi.com/v1/results?mode=fg-image' \
    --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---0123456789' \
    --header 'x-rapidapi-host: background-removal4.p.rapidapi.com' \
    --header 'x-rapidapi-key: MY_API_KEY' \
    --form image=@test.jpg
```

Помогите пожалуйста! Докуентация: https://rapidapi.com/api4ai-api4ai-default/api/background-removal4/ Код, предложенный автором не работает.

Comment: Может надо содержимое файла, а не хендл файла передавать? `img.read()` то есть.

Comment: А вы не могли бы приложить тело ответа в вопрос, чтобы было понятно что именно возвращает сервер, помимо 400 кода

Comment: Ответ: {"detail":"There was an error parsing the body"}

Comment: Тут лишний `'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=---0123456789",`, этот заголовок requests сам добавляет

Comment: @gil9red, тогда сервер жалуется, что тип файла неподдерживается, хотя через Test Endpoint на rapidapi файл сервер успешно берёт и возвращает ответ.

Comment: @Alexey, тип... интересно как он тип определяет, мб по расширению файла? Попробуйте вместо img передать кортеж, типа `files={'image': ('img.jpg', img)})` пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/53143960/5909792 . Еще включите логирование запроса requests, чтобы понять как он данные формирует: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/6ba858030661817374aeb24f121b3d1589f2be5a/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L18

Comment: @gil9red, `{"results":[{"status":{"code":"failure","message":"Unsupported media type. Expected one of {'image/png', 'image/jpeg'}. Got ''."},"name":"test.jpeg","md5":"feaba5b7b5c71463d1684d596d203208","entities":[]}]}` теперь ответ таков :) Сервер не видит ни расширения, ни названия

Comment: @Alexey, я бы поигрался с запросом, например указав другое расширение не `img.jpg`, а `img.jpeg`. Или третьим элементом в том кортеже добавил mime-type, который сервер хочет `image/jpeg`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21400085/5909792 .  Если сервер определяет формат по содержимому файла, тогда можно открыть файл в редакторе или вывести через питон первые 100 символов, для jpg файл должен иметь в начале что-то вроде `JFIF`, и убедиться что там действительно jpg, а не что-то другое

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо большое! Теперь ответ сервера нужный: `{"results":[{"status":{"code":"ok""message":"Success"}"name":"test.jpg""md5":"feaba5b7b5c71463d1684d596d203208""entities":[{"kind":"image""name":"general-fg-image""image":"BASE64 encoded image"}]}]}` 1. Убран заголовок 'content-type'; 
2. В кортеже были добавлены 'test.jpg' до переменной img, а также 'image/jpeg' и {'Expires': '0'} после неё в requests body

Comment: @Alexey, пожалуйста :) Оформите, пожалуйста, ответ на собственный вопрос с примером решения :)

Answer (score 3):

Проблема была решена следующим образом:

1. Убран заголовок 'content-type';
2. В кортеже были добавлены 'test.jpg' до переменной img, а также 'image/jpeg' и {'Expires': '0'} после неё в requests body (подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399845/mime-type-for-requests-post-file/21400085#21400085)

Код:

```
import requests
    
url = 'https://background-removal4.p.rapidapi.com/v1/results?mode=fg-image'
    
headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "MY_API_KEY",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "background-removal4.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
    
with open('test.jpg', 'rb') as img:
    response = requests.post(
        url, headers=headers, files={'image': ('test.jpg', img, 'image/jpeg',  {'Expires': '0'})})
    
print(response.text)
```

Ответ сервера:

```
{"results":[{"status":{"code":"ok""message":"Success"}"name":"test.jpg""md5":"feaba5b7b5c71463d1684d596d203208""entities":[{"kind":"image""name":"general-fg-image""image":"BASE64 encoded image"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

## О документации RapidAPI

RapidAPI сам автоматически генерирует примеры использования API для множества языков и библиотек. К сожалению авторы не могут редактировать эти примеры. Поэтому некоторые авторы пишут свою документацию и выкладывают в раздел about. Вот, например, авторская документация для сервиса, которым вы хотели воспользоваться: https://rapidapi.com/api4ai-api4ai-default/api/background-removal4/details

## Как послать изображение

Что касается непосредственно использования Background Removal API, то там используется обычный POST запрос multipart/form-data (такой же, какой отправляет HTML форма) с изображением в поле image.

## Примеры на bash

Проще всего воспользоваться `curl`. Эта утилита сама угадает MIME-тип по расширению. Поэтому часть header-ов можно не указывать.

Просто послать изображение с помощью `curl`:

```sh
curl -X POST -F"image=@PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE.JPG" \
https://background-removal4.p.rapidapi.com/v1/results \
--header 'x-rapidapi-key: YOUR_RAPIDAPI_KEY'
```

Если у вас в системе есть утилиты `jq` и `base64`, то можно сразу сохранить полученное png изображение на диск с помощью этой команды:

```sh
curl -X POST -F"image=@PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE.JPG" \
https://background-removal4.p.rapidapi.com/v1/results \
--header 'x-rapidapi-key: YOUR_RAPIDAPI_KEY' -s | \
jq -r '.results[0].entities[0].image' | \
base64 -Dd -o PATH_TO_OUTPUT.PNG
```

## Пример на Python с использование `requests` и `mimetypes`

Для определения MIME типов в Python можно воспользоваться модулем `mimetypes`:

```py
import os
import requests
import mimetypes

URL = 'https://background-removal4.p.rapidapi.com/v1/results'
YOUR_RAPIDAPI_KEY = ...
PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE = ...

with open(PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE, 'rb') as img:
    mt = mimetypes.guess_type(PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE)[0]
    response = requests.post(
        URL,
        headers={'x-rapidapi-key': YOUR_RAPIDAPI_KEY},
        files={'image': (os.path.basename(PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE), img, mt)})

print(response.text)
```